# CInt using in VBA (skipping empty cells)

Tags: excel, vba

Using `CInt` in `VBA` but there are some empty cells. It needs to skip and go to next one

```
Do While i < 400
    Str = Cells(i, NOfMonths)

    Num = CInt(Str)
    If Num > 120 And Num < 500 Then
        Cells(i, 13) = ">10"

    Else
        ws2.Select
        On Error Resume Next
        result = Application.VLookup(Str, ws2.Range("A3:B125"), 2, False)

        If (Err <> 0) Then
        Else
            ws1.Select
            Cells(i, 13) = result
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: `If Str<>"" then ... End if ` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if the cell is empty or not.

```
Do While i < 400
    Str = Cells(i, NOfMonths)

    '~~> Check for blank cell
    If Len(Trim(Str)) <> 0 Then
        Num = CInt(Str)
        If Num > 120 And Num < 500 Then
            Cells(i, 13) = ">10"
        Else
            ws2.Select
            On Error Resume Next
            result = Application.VLookup(Str, ws2.Range("A3:B125"), 2, False)

            If (Err <> 0) Then
            Else
                ws1.Select
                Cells(i, 13) = result
            End If
        End If
    End If
Loop
```

Also please do not use `Reserved` words as variables. `Str` is a reserved word. You could use `Strg` in lieu of that.